# SwiftUI NavigationButton: How to navigate to different destinations

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode11

```
List(list) { feature in
                NavigationButton(destination: destination)) {
                    ListCell(feature: feature)
                }
            }
```

I want to navigate to different Views when tapping on row by changing the **destination** view instead of single View for each row

is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a way.

This is the main body with a fully dynamic "cell". The `tableRow` function renders the content of the cell, while the `destination` function computes the target of the `NavigationButton`.

```swift
   var body: some View {
        List {
           // Renders the table with all the active conversations
           ForEach(appData.currentUser.conversations) { conversation in
                NavigationButton(destination: self.destination(for: conversation) ) { 
                    self.tableRow(for: conversation)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The `destination` function is very simple, the only "trick" here is the usage of `AnyView` as a return type.

```swift
private func destination (for conversation: Conversation) -> AnyView {
    if conversation.mode == .personal {
        return AnyView(ConversationDetail(conversation: conversation))

    } else if conversation.mode == .groupChat {
        return AnyView(ConversationDetailGroup(conversation: conversation))

    } else {
        return AnyView(ConversationDetailJoin(conversation: conversation))
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that because views are structs, you will be navigating to a new view each time you click on a row. You are not modifying a single view, you are tearing down the old one and building a new one based on the inputs to the destination function.

Comment: @DLAN Base on what you said, do you have a better approach to this?

Comment: No, partly because I haven't done SwiftUI in 10 months (waiting for a bit more maturity), and partly because I don't think it is necessarily bad to have that happen, it is just something to be aware of. If it works fine, no need to fix anything. If you start running into issues because of it, then I would recommend posting a new question.